# Add default value option in select tag

Tags: reactjs

I use a select tag in my application:

```js
<Select
    showSearch={false}
    defaultValue={["Lucy"]}
    mode="multiple"
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Select a person"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    onChange={onChange}
    onFocus={onFocus}
    onBlur={onBlur}
    onSearch={onSearch}
    filterOption={(input, option) =>
      option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    }
  >
    <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
    <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
    <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
  </Select>,
  document.getElementById("container")
```

I want to set a default selected value for this `Select`, to get something like this:
[image]

So, when i will open first time this dropdown, i want to have a default value selected in the way like in the image. I tried `defaultValue` but it does not work as i described., So, how to achive what i described above?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/select-with-search-field-ant-design-demo-4f9op?file=/index.js:410-955

Comment: default value array element should be the same as value attribute of Option. In your case lowercase.

Comment: use defaultValues = 'lucy' you are passing an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing `['Lucy']` (uppercased) as default value but the values provided in the options are 'lucy', 'jack', and 'tom' all lowercased. That is why the `Select` treats the default value as another value.

Solution either provide the default value same as used in options `defaultValue={["lucy"]}` or use uppercased values in `Option` if you want the defaultValue to be uppercased as well.

```js
<Select
    showSearch={false}
    defaultValue={["lucy"]}
    mode="multiple"
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Select a person"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    onChange={onChange}
    onFocus={onFocus}
    onBlur={onBlur}
    onSearch={onSearch}
    filterOption={(input, option) =>
      option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    }
  >
    <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
    <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
    <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
  </Select>,
  document.getElementById("container")
```

Codesandbox demo, [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-with-search-field-ant-design-demo-3lozx?file=/index.js)

Answer (score 1):

The option value is 'lucy', and you set the default value to 'Lucy' (with a capital letter). Therefore, the default value does not work. Set the default value to 'lucy'.